# TFS command lines with interface

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, team-foundation-server

I am using TFS 2012. I am using [TFS command line utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to `check-in` to `get latest version` etc.
So if i use command line then if any conflict comes while checkin then it gives message like conflicts found.

But i want command line or a method by which i can checkin the code silently, but if any conflicts comes then visual studio interface should appear asking me what to do with conflicts(like automerge,take server version etc option which appears in visual studio). Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was given by a user from [msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2585e412-d29f-4501-b540-4c3eae6825c4/tfs-command-lines-with-interface?forum=tfsgeneral)

If I use c:\projects>tf checkin /noprompt, I'll get an error message in prompt, but no dialogue box shows up

If I use c:\projects>tf checkin, I'll get a dialogue box like the screenshot below:

[image]